# Override ember component template with template from addon (in-repo)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I want to create an in-repo addon to make certain modifications (styles, templates, etc.) to an existing ember app in an encapsulated way, but I'm having troubles overriding the templates.

Right now, I'm trying to override an existing component template with the template from a component with the same name in the in-repo addon. My code looks something like this:

```js
// my-app/app/templates/components/foo.hbs
<h1>Some headline<h1>

// my-app/app/lib/my-addon/app/templates/components/foo.hbs
<h1>A different headline<h1> // -> this never shows up
```

I've tried a lot of switching around the template structure (like putting it in `/addons` or `/app` and linking to the template in different ways, but without success. My problem is that ember never uses the template from the addon.

If the component within the addon has a different name, like `foobar.hbs`, I can call it without a problem.

I'm currently looking through the source code and docs, trying to make sense of this. Is this even accomplishable the way I imagine it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think thats possible. At least not just by putting a file somewhere. The app overrides the addon, not the other way around. So the addon can provide a default behavior and the app can override that.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create the component in your ember app which, initially, will mean the component renders as nothing as it's a brand new, empty component. Then you'd dig into your `node_modules`, find the component file and template and copy over what you'd need to work with.

Here's an example. While working with `ember-cli-jsonapi-pagination`, I need to customize the `paginate-collection` component:

1. I created the component in my application.
2. I looked at the source: https://github.com/BookingSync/ember-cli-jsonapi-pagination/tree/master/app
3. In `components/paginate-collection/component.js` I copied over the component code, but you should be able to import it as well.
4. In `components/paginate-collection/template.hbs` I modified the template as needed.